# ElasticSearch Kubernetes Setup with Skaffold

Tags: elasticsearch, kubernetes

I love elastic search so on my new project I have been trying to make it work on Kubernetes and skaffold

this is the yaml file I wrote:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: eks-depl
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: eks
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: eks
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: eks
          image: elasticsearch:7.17.0
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: eks-srv
spec:
  selector:
    app: eks
  ports:
    - name: db
      protocol: TCP
      port: 9200
      targetPort: 9200
    - name: monitoring
      protocol: TCP
      port: 9300
      targetPort: 9300
```

After I run skaffold dev it shows to be working by Kubernetes but after a few seconds it crashes and goes down.

I can't understand what I am doing wrong.

[image: This is where the problem seems to occur]

After I have updated my config files as Mr. Harsh Manvar it worked like a charm but currently I am facing another issue. The client side says the following....

Btw I am using ElasticSearch version 7.11.1 and Client side module "@elastic/elasticsearch^7.11.1"

[image]

Comment: did you check the logs information is not helpful to debug more, i would suggest to check logs and if possible you can use the helm or elasticsearch also.

Comment: Thank you for your reply @Harsh Manvar. I am currently checking the logs and will the update question soon. But is my configuration correct ? Is that how you setup a elastic search docker image on Kubernetes ?

Comment: No, you have to use the PVC disk to storing the data, way you have setup is kindof stateless configuration there could be chances if yolu POD or container restart your data will be wiped off. you have to use the PVC and cronjob also for auto backup etc. that why suggested to try out the helm chart as it auto create the PVC disk and all in single command

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is example YAML file you should consider running if you are planning to run the single Node elasticsearch cluster on the Kubernetes

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: StatefulSet
metadata:
  labels:
    app: elasticsearch
    component: elasticsearch
    release: elasticsearch
  name: elasticsearch
  namespace: default
spec:
  podManagementPolicy: OrderedReady
  replicas: 1
  revisionHistoryLimit: 10
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: elasticsearch
      component: elasticsearch
      release: elasticsearch
  serviceName: elasticsearch
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: elasticsearch
        component: elasticsearch
        release: elasticsearch
    spec:
      containers:
      - env:
        - name: cluster.name
          value: es_cluster
        - name: ELASTIC_PASSWORD
          value: xyz-xyz
        - name: discovery.type
          value: single-node
        - name: path.repo
          value: backup/es-backup
        - name: ES_JAVA_OPTS
          value: -Xms512m -Xmx512m
        - name: bootstrap.memory_lock
          value: "false"
        - name: xpack.security.enabled
          value: "true"
        image: elasticsearch:7.3.2
        imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
        name: elasticsearch
        ports:
        - containerPort: 9200
          name: http
          protocol: TCP
        - containerPort: 9300
          name: transport
          protocol: TCP
        resources:
          limits:
            cpu: 451m
            memory: 1250Mi
          requests:
            cpu: 250m
            memory: 1000Mi
        securityContext:
          privileged: true
          runAsUser: 1000
        terminationMessagePath: /dev/termination-log
        terminationMessagePolicy: File
        volumeMounts:
        - mountPath: /usr/share/elasticsearch/data
          name: elasticsearch-data
      dnsPolicy: ClusterFirst
      initContainers:
      - command:
        - sh
        - -c
        - chown -R 1000:1000 /usr/share/elasticsearch/data
        - sysctl -w vm.max_map_count=262144
        - chmod 777 /usr/share/elasticsearch/data
        - chomod 777 /usr/share/elasticsearch/data/node
        - chmod g+rwx /usr/share/elasticsearch/data
        - chgrp 1000 /usr/share/elasticsearch/data
        image: busybox:1.29.2
        imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
        name: set-dir-owner
        resources: {}
        securityContext:
          privileged: true
        terminationMessagePath: /dev/termination-log
        terminationMessagePolicy: File
        volumeMounts:
        - mountPath: /usr/share/elasticsearch/data
          name: elasticsearch-data
      restartPolicy: Always
      schedulerName: default-scheduler
      securityContext: {}
      terminationGracePeriodSeconds: 10
  updateStrategy:
    type: OnDelete
  volumeClaimTemplates:
  - metadata:
      creationTimestamp: null
      name: elasticsearch-data
    spec:
      accessModes:
      - ReadWriteOnce
      resources:
        requests:
          storage: 10Gi
      volumeMode: Filesystem
```

i would also recommand checking out the helm charts of the elasticsearch :

```
1 . https://github.com/elastic/helm-charts/tree/master/elasticsearch

2. https://github.com/helm/charts/tree/master/stable/elasticsearch
```

you can expose the above stateful set using the service and use the further with the application.

Comment: Thankksssss aaa lottt @Harsh Manvar.

Comment: make this is not for production use you can use this for development while for prod please refer helm chart link with single command you can auto deploy everything so. feel free to comment if you face any issue.

Comment: you might need to just change the elasticsearch version (docker image version) in yaml i was using 7.3.2 so it's old, please update as per need.

Comment: Oh yes, Thank you. I have updated the Elasticsearch to a newer version.

Comment: I am facing another issue currently. The client says this "ProductNotSupportedSecurityError: The client is unable to verify that the server is Elasticsearch due to security privileges on the server side. Some functionality may not be compatible if the server is running an unsupported product."

Comment: I have updated the question with the following issue. Please do check

Comment: oh i am really sorry i share config with password, you need to remove this 4 line, `xpack.security.enabled`, `ELASTIC_PASSWORD` and value of both also.

Comment: what this config do is secure and set the basic auth password on cluster level for security.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/241852/discussion-between-jean-and-harsh-manvar).

Comment: ohh ok. Np you don't need to apologise. Btw even if we have the auth password so to login from the client side do we pass in the password with the new Client connection ?

Comment: yes you have to pass the password in connection header it will be like bearer token we pass as auth header. still you might need to update the YAML once, i kept xyz but we have to add base64 encoded username and password in it instead of xyz. i dont think plain value xyz will work, you have to encode `username:password` as format and paste base64 encoded value to yaml.

Comment: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/http-clients.html

Comment: Ohh I got it. Thank you