# What updates should be made in Elasticsearch statefulset file for version 8.0.0?

Tags: elasticsearch, kubernetes, kibana, elastic-stack, elk

I had created the a stateful set file for Elasticsearch 7.16.1 but on upgrading the ELK stack to 8.0.0, I get this error in the logs of the elastic pod:- `"java.lang.IllegalStateException: failed to obtain node locks, tried [/usr/share/elasticsearch/data];` maybe these locations are not writable or multiple nodes were started on the same data path?

Likely root cause:

```
java.nio.file.NoSuchFileException: /usr/share/elasticsearch/data/node.lock"
```

[Elastic pod error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aUk3i.png)

Kibana pod gives this error:-

```
"curl: (7) Failed to connect to elastic-cluster port 9200: Connection refused"
```

[Kibana pod error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nmt4d.png)

I didn't get this error with the **7.16.1** version.

Should I make some changes in the statefulset files or any other files? Please help me solve this.

Comment: share your yaml statefulsets file for ES, are you changing any file permission or so ?

Comment: `sudo mkdir -p $PWD/elasticsearch/datasudo & chmod 777 -R $PWD/elasticsearch/data`

Comment: I added this command in my file but the error still persists

Comment: Did you added this as init container command or so ?

Comment: I don't have an init container for the pod

Answer (score 1):

Adding the following initContainers in my statefulset.yaml fixed the issue for me:

```
initContainers:
- name: fix-permissions

  image: busybox

  command: ["sh", "-c", "chown -R 1000:1000 /usr/share/elasticsearch/data"]

  securityContext:

          privileged: true

  volumeMounts:

  - name: local-storage

    mountPath: /usr/share/elasticsearch/data
```

Comment: just to share if anyone looking for whole ready statefulset : https://stackoverflow.com/a/71044647/5525824

Answer (score 0):

most likely the folder /usr/share/elasticsearch/data doesnt have required permissions.

include init container in your deployment manifest and provide appropriate permissions needed by the elastic process to write the index data.

Comment: I tied adding changing to root user with the following commands but I got this error "chmod: changing permissions of '/root': Operation not permitted":
$ su - root
$ chmod o+w /root

Comment: you should be changing permissions on data folder that is /usr/share/elasticsearch/data